# Symfony 1.4 Error 400 on the home page in prod env (not in dev env)

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I have made an tested an application on my computer and all is working fine (I used only the dev environment via the frontend_dev.php page).

When I deploy this application on the test server, I have the error 400 Bad Request below:

> Bad Request
>
> Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.

I accessed to the website with the normal URL.
I'm using symfony 1.4 with doctrine (no others plugins are involved), wamp 2 (php 5.3, apache 2.0.59).

If I try to access the application with the dev environment, it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking if the `no_script` property on your application `setting.yml` file. If should be set to False, clear cache and try again

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much Guiman. You have leaded me to the answer.

The `no_script_name` property wasn't the origin of the problem. Instead, I have my `.htaccess` in the web directory which was badly generated (I swear on my pet's head that I haven't edited this file before). Below is the file generated by symfony (the bold attribute isn't working within the code one, look at the last line):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  # uncomment the following line, if you are having trouble
  # getting no_script_name to work
  #RewriteBase /

  # we skip all files with .something
  #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \..+$
  #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html$
  #RewriteRule .* - [L]

  # we check if the .html version is here (caching)
  RewriteRule ^$ index.html [QSA]
  RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

  # no, so we redirect to our front web controller
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

And this is the updated one (again, look at the last line):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  # uncomment the following line, if you are having trouble
  # getting no_script_name to work
  #RewriteBase /

  # we skip all files with .something
  #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \..+$
  #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html$
  #RewriteRule .* - [L]

  # we check if the .html version is here (caching)
  RewriteRule ^$ index.html [QSA]
  RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

  # no, so we redirect to our front web controller
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ **/myApp/index.php** [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

I don't know what happened but I will check on the symfony website I there are similar issues.

Comment: Well that's would have been my second approach :P, it's great to know that you could figure it out yourself! Cheers

Comment: If the *no_script_name * was not the issue, why did you accept the other answer then that says it's the issue?